# Find all local extremums of $f(x)=x^{2}e^{-x}$ and decide if these are global extremums

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, curves

As all my other questions, this one isn't homework (it's preparation for an exam).

**I'd like to know if I did everything correctly.** In my previous task, I had a mistake in the first derivation. But for this task, I think everything is alright.

> Find all local extremums of the following function and decide if these
>   are global extremums (i.e. maxima or rather minima of the function on
>   its entire domain) or not:
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto x^{2}e^{-x} \in \mathbb{R}$

I have started by checking the behavior of $f$ towards $+- \infty$ to see it more clear / see at all if the extremums are global or local. And for finding the limit, I had to use L'Hôpitals rule twice (not shown to keep it short).

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=\infty$$

This already tells me that on the left (negative) side of the coordinate system, there will be endlessly extremums. $\Rightarrow$ The function cannot have any global extremums.

Now derivate $f$ and calculate the extremum:

$$f'(x)=e^{-x}(2x-x^{2})$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$f'(x)=0$$

$$0=\frac{1}{e^x}(2x-x^{2})$$

$$0=2x-x^{2}$$

$$x^{2}=2x$$

$$x=2$$

Now use the $2^{nd}$ derivation to check if this is a maximum or minimum. It's a local maximum in point $P(2|\frac{4}{e^{2}})$.

Comment: You should also check for zero , you missed it $$x(x-2)=0$$

Comment: additionally, when you found the limits at infinity and negative infinity, you can only rule out the fact that the function has a global maximum. The function can (and does) have a global minimum

Comment: Ouch >.<
Thank you very much. This is so frustrating all tasks I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost right. But at the $0=2x-x^{2}$ step, you cannot conclude that $x=2$. Indeed, $0=2x-x^{2}=x(2-x)\implies x=0,2$. Thus, you must also check $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

From your penultimate line you should also deduce that $x=0$ which gives the minimum of zero

Answer (score 3):

Your first conclusion that "This already tells me that on the left (negative) side of the coordinate system, there will be endlessly extremums." is wrong, in general. A simple counter-example is $f(x)=e^{-x}$ which possesses the limits mentioned in the question but does not have endlessly extrema.

Moreover in the second derivation, you missed $x=0$ which will give you the minimum when you calculate the second derivative.